NestJS: Recognising generics in dependency injection
I am trying to create a NestJS module that carries generic information across in the injection token. I cannot figure out how to tell the compiler to recognise this - I know I am blurring the line between compile-time and run-time but perhaps there is a way!
I have the following module.  It Zod wraps the native NestJS caching module, and provides a typesafe interface into serialisating/deserialising any cache entries.
export class CachingModule {
  static register(schema: ZodObject<any>): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: CachingModule,
      imports: [
        CacheModule.registerAsync<CacheModuleOptions>({
          imports: [EnvironmentModule],
          inject: [EnvService],
          useFactory: async (env: EnvService) => {
            const redisCache = await redisStore({
              socket: {
                host: env.get('REDIS_CACHE_HOST'),
                port: env.get('REDIS_CACHE_PORT'),
              },
              ttl: env.get('REDIS_CACHE_TTL'),
            })
            return ({
              store: redisCache,
              isGlobal: false,
            })
          },
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CACHE_SCHEMA,
          useValue: schema,
        },
        {
          provide: CachingService,
          useClass: CachingService<typeof schema>,  <--- this here
        },
      ],
      exports: [CachingService],
    }
  }
}

My service looks something like this:
type TSchema = ZodObject<any>

type InferSchema<T> = T extends z.ZodObject<infer U> ? {
  [K in keyof U]: U[K] extends z.ZodType ?
    z.infer<U[K]> extends Record<string, any> ?
        { [P in keyof z.infer<U[K]>]: z.infer<U[K]>[P] } :
      z.infer<U[K]>
    : never
} : never

type StringKeys<T> = keyof T & string

@Injectable()
export class CachingService<TSchema extends CacheSchema> {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cacheManager: Cache,
    @Inject(CACHE_SCHEMA) private readonly schema: TSchema,
  ) {}

  async get<K extends StringKeys<InferSchema<TSchema>>>(
    key: K,
  ): Promise<InferSchema<TSchema>[K] | undefined> {
    const result = await this.cacheManager.get(key)
    return this.parseResult(key, result)
  }

  ...


In my app.module file, I register this with a zod validator like so, where cacheSchema is something like z.object{ name: z.string() }):
@Module({
  imports: [
    CachingModule.register(cacheSchema),
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}


This all compiles and works well enough, but whenever I use CachingService the compiler can't resolve the supplied validator in the DI framework and it needs to be supplied manually:
  constructor(
    private readonly cachingService: CachingService<typeof cacheSchema>,
  ) {}

I understand I am giving the compiler a generic here CachingService that is requiring a type so it can resolve, but this is just the end result of many hours of trying to get it to work.
If I remove the generics and import statically from where cacheSchema is set I can get this to work without issue, but then my tests are coupled to the schema definition and it makes it annoyingly onerous to extend from an end user perspetive.
Question:
Can I change my code / tell the compiler to automatically resolve the type supplied in the CachingService injection token so that I don't need to provider generic arguments for it?  Or in code format:
Injection token:
{
  provide: CachingService,                 <--- injection token
  useClass: CachingService<typeof schema>  <--- supplied generic
}

Injected Provider:
private readonly cachingService: CachingService<typeof cacheSchema>,
                                                ^
                                      How do I remove this requirement?



You're right about mixing up compile time and runtime, what if you use factory to register the service instead and passthrough the schema as zod any object so that it can figure it out completely at runtime?
{
provide: CachingService,
useFactory: (cacheManager: Cache, schema: ZodObject) => {
return new CachingService(cacheManager, schema);
},
inject: [CACHE_MANAGER, CACHE_SCHEMA],
},
